# Delphi 11 does not colour Components

Tags: colors, components

On Delphi 11 I cannot color components, neither at design stage nor at running time.
Can anyone help please?
Thank you

On selecting the color property of a component the color does not change. Even when running the program no color change.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> User Interface -> Form Designer -> Enable VCL Styles & Uncheck Mimick System Styles had the same problem